# How can I use Excel Data Validation for a U.S. Zip Code?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to use Excel data validation to restrict data entry into a field for U.S. zip codes.  I'm looking for confirmation that this formula is complete or looking for someone to post a better formula.

**Data Validation Restrictions**

Here are the restrictions I came up with:

- 10 digit string with 5 digits followed by a dash and then 4 digits
- 5 digit number
- 5 digit numeric string that includes leading zeroes (but see below for the lowest allowed number)
- The lowest first 5 digits in any zip code is 00501
- For zip code 00501, either text "00501" or the number 501 are acceptable.

**Validation Formula**

Here's the validation formula I'm using now.  I'm looking for confirmation that this is complete or a better validation formula.

`=IF(  ISNUMBER(1*$AD$36),  AND( 1*$AD$36>=501, 1*$AD$36<=99999),   AND(  LEN($AD$36)=10,  ISNUMBER(1*LEFT($AD$36,5)),  1*LEFT($AD$36,5)>=501,  1*LEFT($AD$36,5)<=9999,  ISNUMBER(1*RIGHT($AD$36,4)),  MID($AD$36,6,1)="-"))`

**Formula Explanation**

- All instances of `*1` are to convert numbers saved as text into actual numbers.
- If the cell value is numeric (for example, 501 or 12345) then check to make sure it is a valid number between 501 and 99999 (longer zip codes must include a dash, making them non-numeric).
- If the cell value is -not- numeric then check that the string has a length of 10, the first 5 characters are numbers, the 6th character is a dash, and the last 4 characters are numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use custom formatting for those cells in order to avoid dealing with numbers and text, this would greatly simplify your work.

What if you use a custom format for these cells and only input numbers?

For example, use the following custom format (Right Click -> Format Cells -> [tab]Number -> Custom) :

```
[<=99999]00000;[>99999]00000-0000
```

Then, your formula to check the validity of each entry will look like:

```
# Absolute reference to the cell ($x$x) may not be necessary but I kept it...

=AND(ISNUMBER($AD$36),IF(LEN($AD$36)>5,INT(LEFT($AD$36,LEN($AD$36)-4)),$AD$36)>=501,$AD$36<=999999999)
```

Old check: <strike>=AND(ISNUMBER($AD$36),$AD$36>=501,$AD$36<=999999999)</strike>

This what it will look like:

| Unformatted | Formatted | Validation | Info |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 400 | 00400 | FALSE | too small |
| 501 | 00501 | TRUE |  |
| 10008 | 10008 | TRUE |  |
| 99999ABCD | 99999ABCD | FALSE | contain characters |
| 100009 | 00010-0009 | FALSE | first digits too small |
| 999999 | 00099-9999 | FALSE | first digits too small |
| 550000000 | 55000-0000 | TRUE |  |
| 1234512345 | 123451-2345 | FALSE | too long |

Comment: FYI the first 5 is the zip, anything after the hyphen is a subset of the zip (more narrow location). So 00010-0009 fails because 00010 is not valid.

Comment: Thanks for the info, so a different condition is required at check level. I updated my answer but it looks like that's not the way you want to go.